# How to display inline "input" elements, surrounded by divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML code, with 3 input fields :

> ```
>        <div class="field" >
>           <input placeholder="Firstname" class="firstname" id="firstname_field"  name="firstname" size="30" value="" type="text" >
>        </div>
>        <div class="field" >
>            <input placeholder="Lastname" class="lastname" id="lastname_field"  name="lastname" size="30" value="" type="text" >
>        </div>
>        <div class="field" >
>            <input placeholder="Email" class="email" id="email_field"  name="email" size="30" value="" type="text" >
>        </div>
> ```

Currently, because they are surrounded by div's, they display in block : http://jsfiddle.net/k2Nqp/159/
I need the 2 first fields to display "inline" and not as block, and the 3rd one to stay as a block.

Easy if you put "display:inline-block" inside the div's. But the tricky part here, is that I don't have any control on this HTML code, as it's auto-generated by a shortcode. I can add CSS, using the already existing classes, or even javascript (I used javascript to insert the placeholder)

And since the 3 divs have the same class, they would display all block or all inline, so I can only work on the input fields. Unfortunately I tried specified "inline-block" to the input fields, and it's not working.

Any idea on how to make this work ?
Thank you !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k2Nqp/161/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below CSS, to achieve your expected result

```
.field{
 display:inline; 
}
#email_field{
  display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/k2Nqp/164/

display:inline will allow all fields to be displayed in inline and display:block on third field , will make it block element and gets displayed in separate line

Comment: Simple and effective :) Thak you +1 !

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this with a more complex set of fields i would suggest checking out the :nth-of-type() and :nth-child() css selectors.

```css
.field {
  display: inline-block; 
}
.field:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="field" >
  <input placeholder="Firstname" class="firstname" id="firstname_field" name="firstname" size="30" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="field" >
  <input placeholder="Lastname" class="lastname" id="lastname_field" name="lastname" size="30" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="field" >
  <input placeholder="Email" class="email" id="email_field" name="email" size="30" value="" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, my form is indeed more complex and the example was only to be able to find a solution that I could reproduce :). I'v used the once above successfully, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use nth-child() selector to align your div's

```
div:nth-child(1),div:nth-child(2) {
    display:inline;
}
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/k2Nqp/163/)

[Read about nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: That was a very good answer ! I used the other one because I was more confortable with it, but this one is definitely better for very long forms. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The below CSS rule will select all of the elements with the field class except for the last one and apply the `display` style with value `inline-block`.

```
.field:not(:last-child) {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: In my real form, I have more fields below the email, so the solution just above would sork well in my case, but yours in definitely useful for the case of the last field beeing the email ! Thanks